# android scrollable activity layout

Tags: android

I am trying to make my activity screen where there is a form to be filled scrollable but unfortunately, when I tried it crashed the app. I have the following xml for that activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:textDirection="anyRtl"
    tools:context=".AddDiscountActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="@string/discountLocationLabel"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/shopLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/shopCity"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/shopDiscount"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="@string/discountDurationLabel"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/shopDiscountDuration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/shopDiscount"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/shopDiscount"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/discountRateLabel"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
        android:text="@string/discountPublishButtonLabel"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:onClick="SubmitData"
        android:width="250dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/shopCity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/shopName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >


    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/shopDiscount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/shopLocation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/shopLocation"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/shopName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"> 
         <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/categoriesSpinner"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="@string/discountCategoryLabel"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/categoriesSpinner"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/shopName"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="206dp"
        android:text="@string/discountCityLabel"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/shopCity"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:text="@string/discountShopLabel"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/addDiscountMsg"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textDirection="anyRtl" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And when I tried to add the following after defining RelativeLayout and before closing RelativeLayout, it broke the app immediately when I run it.

```
    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             >

            ...........
</ScrollView>
```

How can I make it scrollable?

Comment: Can you please post the entire xml file?

Comment: This is the entire xml file for this activity my friend

Comment: OK, so where is the close tag of `</RelativeLayout>`.

Comment: at the bottom of posted code. Make sure you scroll down

Answer (score 13):

Your app crashes because ScrollView can host only one direct child.
Direct from official documentation:

> Layout container for a view hierarchy that can be scrolled by the
>   user, allowing it to be larger than the physical display. A ScrollView
>   is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing
>   the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout
>   manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that is often
>   used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a
>   vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through.

Look this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html.

To solve your xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:textDirection="anyRtl"
    tools:context=".AddDiscountActivity" >

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                android:text="@string/discountLocationLabel"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/shopLocation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/shopCity"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_below="@+id/shopDiscount"
                android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
                android:text="@string/discountDurationLabel"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/shopDiscountDuration"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/shopDiscount"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/shopDiscount"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/discountRateLabel"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                android:text="@string/discountPublishButtonLabel"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="SubmitData"
                android:width="250dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/shopCity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/shopName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/shopDiscount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/shopLocation"
                android:layout_below="@+id/shopLocation"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/shopName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text"> 
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/categoriesSpinner"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
                android:text="@string/discountCategoryLabel"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/categoriesSpinner"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/shopName"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginTop="206dp"
                android:text="@string/discountCityLabel"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/shopCity"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                android:text="@string/discountShopLabel"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/addDiscountMsg"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textDirection="anyRtl" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: if I do this, it starts telling me to remove         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3" similar code in all areas of the xml file. Will removing them not destroy the app itself?

Comment: It tell you that, because  "android:layout_alignRight" is property of a RelativeLayout, you can change the LinearLayout to RelativeLayout

Comment: i don;t understand this... you asy it can only have one direct chlid, yet your example has several direct chilsdern./

Comment: Nop, it had the LinearLayout as direct child of the scrollView. All the other child's belong to the LinearLayout. @PootieTang

Comment: ahhh i see... was confused because no indentation

Answer (score 8):

Do it like this , it will work :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
android:textDirection="anyRtl"
tools:context=".AddDiscountActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="@string/discountLocationLabel"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/shopLocation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/shopCity"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/shopDiscount"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text="@string/discountDurationLabel"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/shopDiscountDuration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/shopDiscount"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/shopDiscount"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/discountRateLabel"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
    android:text="@string/discountPublishButtonLabel"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:onClick="SubmitData"
    android:width="250dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/shopCity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/shopName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" >


</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/shopDiscount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/shopLocation"
    android:layout_below="@+id/shopLocation"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/shopName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text"> 
     <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/categoriesSpinner"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="@string/discountCategoryLabel"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/categoriesSpinner"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/shopName"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="206dp"
    android:text="@string/discountCityLabel"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/shopCity"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:text="@string/discountShopLabel"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/addDiscountMsg"
    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textDirection="anyRtl" />

  </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Hope help you

Answer (score 3):

I think you must enclose your relative layout in your scrollview ( before defining and after closing ) .

EDIT : You must also enclose your relative layout in Liner Layout

ex :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/scroll"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fillViewport="true"
   android:stackFromBottom="true"
   android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" >

   <LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <RelativeLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/background"
     android:paddingBottom="16dp"
     android:paddingLeft="16dp"
     android:paddingRight="16dp"
     android:paddingTop="16dp"
     android:textDirection="anyRtl"
     tools:context=".AddDiscountActivity" >
  </RelativeLayout>

  </LinearLayout>

</SrcollView>
```

Comment: That is not allowed. It throws error defining an xmlns before the relative layout

Comment: Ok Sorry. I did it with a Linear Layout inside, it works fine.

Comment: You must also enclose your relative layout in a Linear Layout, it is apparently necessary.